# Resize Rich _ textBox according to Form size

Tags: c#, .net

I need to resize my multiline textbox during runtime and set the width and height according to my main form size so i dont have to use scrollBars when my form is maximised...
already tried the code shown below but the result is nothing any ideas??

```
private void richTextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Size size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(richTextBox2.Text, richTextBox2.Font);
        richTextBox2.Width = size.Width;
        richTextBox2.Height = size.Height;
    }
```

Comment: You should attach that code to your form's `Resize` event instead of your text box's `TextChanged` event. Also, if you are trying to match your textbox's size to the forms size, you should be resizing it to an offset of your form size.

Comment: Do you know about anchors? They may or may not solve your problem, but if they do they are by far easier than writing code!

Comment: Is this winforms? If so (or not) add the appropriate tag.

Comment: The answer is in the comment from TaW. You just want to anchor the RichTextBox to the sides of Form (Left, Top, Right, and Bottom).